# How to specify target directory when using --hive-import in Sqoop?

Tags: import, hive, sqoop

I want to use hive-import command with sqoop.

I can use the --hive-table command to specify the database where I want the file to be created.

However, I do not want the file to be placed in the default hive warehouse. I want it on another specific HDFS location. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the table in Hive in advance, setting the location you want in the `CREATE TABLE` statement, then target that table from Sqoop.